# Are the packages from apt-get remove --auto-remove sendmail safe to remove?

Tags: debian, sendmail, aptitude, remove

Im trying to clean up the mess left by sendmail, My unix knowledge is extremely limited so I would appreciate some help with whether these packages are safe to remove, I have already run `apt-get purge sendmail*`

and when I run `apt-get remove --auto-remove sendmail` these packages are still left over, Im worried that removing them will break something else from working.

```
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  liblockfile-bin liblockfile1 libsigsegv2 m4 procmail
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 5 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

This is pretty much a fresh dedi set-up and I've just gone through securing it, so there arnt that many things installed that could be upset.
This will be production, so I would like to know if these packages are safe to remove though.

Answer (score 1):

Using `apt-get autoremove` gives you the advantage to get rid of all packages not needed as dependencies anymore, not just related to the ones of `sendmail`.
Quoting the manpage:

> autoremove is used to remove packages that were automatically installed to satisfy dependencies for other packages and are now no longer needed.

---

By the way: If you like clean systems (I do!), have a look at [deborphan](https://packages.debian.org/en/jessie/deborphan). Quoting the description:

> deborphan finds "orphaned" packages on your system. It determines which packages have no other packages depending on their installation and shows you a list of these packages. It is most useful when finding libraries, but it can be used on packages in all sections.
>
> This package also includes orphaner, a text menu frontend to deborphan. Please install the recommended packages dialog, gettext-base and apt when you want a working and fully featured orphaner.